# Django - Создание модели внутри другой админ-модели

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, django-orm

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с одной проблемой и очень надеюсь на вашу помощь в решении

Есть две модели:

```
def BigBox(models.Model):
    title = textfield
    date = datetimefield
    author = foreignkey(user)
    # другие поля

def SmallBox(models.Model):
    title = textfield
    url = textfield(blank=true)
    contained_in = foreignkey(BigBox)
    # она может существовать только при связи с (внутри) большой соответственно
```

Я знаю как и могу выводить смол-боксы внутри редактирования в админке биг-бокса (как readonly_fields), но не могу редактировать/добавлять.

---

Собственно в админке есть отдельно две этих модели в виде админ-моделей, но создавать их отдельно от друг друга не совсем практично. По сути в каждом БигБоксе обязательно будет хотя-бы 2 СмолБокса и соответсвенно не существует ни одного СмолБокса вне БигБокса.

Необходимо как-то реализовать поле внутри adminModel БигБокса чтоб прям там создавать/удалять (у них всего одно поле тайтл обязательное, поле урл будет заполняться только для одной СмолБокс внутри одной БигБокс) связанные с ней СмолБоксы.

Надеюсь я понятно объяснил)

Спасибо!

Comment: Используйте [инлайны](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел решение чуть лучше погуглив по английской документации)

Решение называется 'inlines'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects

вопрос закрыт)